# Hide row based on one column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Given the table below

```
  +-----------------------+-----------------+---------------+
  |     212               |   fred          |   red         |
  +-----------------------+-----------------+---------------+
  |     230               |   Tom           |   blue        |
  +-----------------------+-----------------+---------------+
  |     240               |   Bob           |   green       |
  +-----------------------+-----------------+---------------+
  |     253               |   Jim           |   grey        |
  +-----------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to highlight a row using the following without success.

```
  var userid = 212;
  $('tr').find('td:eq(0):contains('+userid+')').parent().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

Which is obviously wrong as it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: So I cut and pasted the exact table from my page and it works in jsfiddle as well. what I haven't said is I have a parent page, click a button and the table loads. Click buttons within the table and it loads the highlight button. The code above is actually on the parent page. Somehow it can't 'see' the table?

Comment: the only correct answer has been proposed by @Joseph, who didn't actually even submit an answer. haha

Comment: @baudday lol I find LeeR's answer satisfactory. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you putting that function inside a DOM-ready call. So it fires once the DOM is ready? (Wow, that was repetitive) I just tried it on jsFiddle and it works fine

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/thHvZ/)

You need something like

```
$('#taget_div').hide().html(data.result).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    var userid = 212;
    $('tr').find('td:eq(0):contains('+userid+')').parent().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: The table is added to the DOM after the page has loaded, however this is attached to a function that can only really run once the table has loaded.

Comment: So the table is created after the page has already loaded? How do you load the table on to the page then?

Comment: from an ajax call  $('#taget_div').hide().html(data.result).fadeIn('slow');

Comment: If you want it to highlight one it has faded in, I have edited my answer above to do that. Hopefully it makes sense to you. Basically, the fadeIn has a callback function that fires once it's finished fading in.

Comment: The table has already loaded. You click a button to select the required row. It just doesn't seem to see the table.

Comment: You need to give us more code. Paste in the html and ANY and ALL javascript that has ANYTHING to do with the table. Otherwise we have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Use jsFiddle if need be

Answer (score 1):

try without `eq(0)` and put the `userid` in quotes

```
$('tr').find('td:contains("'+userid+'")').parent().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uid = "212" //note define uid as a string
$('td:contains('+uid+')').parent().css("background", "yellow")
```

or you can also write

```
$('td:contains('+uid+')').closest("tr").css("background", "yellow")
```

Comment: I like this answer because you got rid of the $('tr').find() chunk.

Answer (score 0):

for the css property, try this instead

```
.css('background', 'yellow');
```

not sure your selector, but that one that is catched by my eyes

Comment: `backgroundColor` will work, [css() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) mentions `...jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting...`